# R merge.data.frame: probabilistic result for ambiguous keys

Tags: r, merge, duplicates

Data and context first: The data in question is

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(A = rep(1, 4), B = c(2, 6, 4, 4), D = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4))
df2 <- data.frame(A = rep(1, 4), C = c(2, 4, 6, 4), D = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8))
```

so we have

```
> df1
  A B   D
1 1 2 0.1
2 1 6 0.2
3 1 4 0.3
4 1 4 0.4
```

and

```
> df2
  A C   D
1 1 2 0.5
2 1 4 0.6
3 1 6 0.7
4 1 4 0.8
```

Now, when doing

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x = c("A", "B"), by.y = c("A", "C"))
```

one gets

```
  A B D.x D.y
1 1 2 0.1 0.5
2 1 4 0.3 0.6
3 1 4 0.3 0.8
4 1 4 0.4 0.6
5 1 4 0.4 0.8
6 1 6 0.2 0.7
```

because of ambiguous combinations of (A,B) and (A,C) values.

The actual question: How could one solve this by randomly distributing the D.x and D.y to the (A,B), e.g. to get equally likely

```
  A B D.x D.y
1 1 2 0.1 0.5
2 1 4 0.3 0.6
5 1 4 0.4 0.8
6 1 6 0.2 0.7
```

and

```
  A B D.x D.y
1 1 2 0.1 0.5
3 1 4 0.3 0.8
4 1 4 0.4 0.6
6 1 6 0.2 0.7
```

as a result of the merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the use of the *data.table* package, you could do it as follows:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- dt1[dt2, on = c(A="A", B="C")][, .(i.D = sample(i.D,1)), by = .(A, B, D)]
```

which gives two possible results (run the code from above several times to see the different results):

```
> DT
   A B   D i.D
1: 1 2 0.1 0.5
2: 1 4 0.3 0.6
3: 1 4 0.4 0.8
4: 1 6 0.2 0.7
```

or:

```
> DT
   A B   D i.D
1: 1 2 0.1 0.5
2: 1 4 0.3 0.8
3: 1 4 0.4 0.6
4: 1 6 0.2 0.7
```

Although this simple solution works, it will be less efficient (especially with regard to memory use). A more memory efficient solution which leads to the same result is:

```
dt1[, indx := 1:.N, keyby = .(A, B)]
dt2[, indx := if(.N > 1L) sample(.N) else 1L, keyby = .(A, C)]
dt1[dt2, on = c(A = "A", B = "C", indx = "indx")]
```

By creating an index in both datasets and sampling that index for the second dataset, you can join on that. This prevents a cartesian join in which all possible combinations are included in the join at first.

---

Used data:

```
dt1 <- data.table(A = rep(1, 4), B = c(2, 6, 4, 4), D = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4))
dt2 <- data.table(A = rep(1, 4), C = c(2, 4, 6, 4), D = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8))
```

---

In base R you could do:

```
df12 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = c("A", "B"), by.y = c("A", "C"))

aggregate( . ~ A + B + D.x, df12, sample, 1)
```

which gives me the following three results in three consequtive runs of the `aggregate` function:

```
# run 1
  A B D.x D.y
1 1 2 0.1 0.5
2 1 6 0.2 0.7
3 1 4 0.3 0.6
4 1 4 0.4 0.8

# run 2
  A B D.x D.y
1 1 2 0.1 0.5
2 1 6 0.2 0.7
3 1 4 0.3 0.8
4 1 4 0.4 0.8

# run 3
  A B D.x D.y
1 1 2 0.1 0.5
2 1 6 0.2 0.7
3 1 4 0.3 0.8
4 1 4 0.4 0.6
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, upvoted. As I am not (yet?) familiar with `data.table`, I would prefer a `base` solution. I will leave it open in case someone chimes in on that. If not, I will accept it after a while.

Comment: @phaebz added a base R solution

Comment: thanks! I thought this to be the point where I should investigate `data.table` more closely. Postponed, for now...